# Why doesn't it save missing keys to translation.json (i18next)?

Tags: reactjs, localization, i18next, react-i18next

I've decided to use `i18next` & `react-i18next` to translate my React application.
Everything worked fine until I wanted to use strings instead of keys. My application tells me that it can not save missing keys to the translation.json file because they are not found [see console errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bw9ja.png). Even though files are there [see tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5J8jQ.png). 
Also I get [this messages in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3Ref.png).
I assume the problem is very trivial, but I just don't get a solution yet, I hope here is someone more experienced and can help me to get rid of this issue.

My i18next config:

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

import Backend from 'i18next-xhr-backend';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';

i18n
.use(Backend)
.use(LanguageDetector)
.use(initReactI18next)
.init({
  react: {
    useSuspense: false, //   <---- this will do the magic
    wait: true
  },
  backend: {
      loadPath: '/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
      addPath: '/locales/add/{{lng}}/{{ns}}',
      allowMultiLoading: true,
    },
  lng: 'en',
  nsSeparator: false,
  keySeparator: false,
  fallbackLng: 'en',
  fallbackNS: 'translation',
  debug: true,
  ns: ["translation", "header", "random"],
  defaultNS: "translation",
  saveMissing: true
 });

 i18n
 .loadNamespaces(['translation','header'])
 .then(() => {});

 i18n.on('missingKey', function(lngs, namespace, key, res) {console.log(key)});

 export default i18n;
```

My index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import i18n from './i18n/i18n';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';
import * as serviceWorker from  './registerServiceWorker';
import {I18nextProvider} from 'react-i18next';


ReactDOM.render(
    <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
        <App/>
    </I18nextProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
serviceWorker.register();
```

I use key like this:

```
{t('Need to save this text')}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you are loading namespaces twice? As you already defined them in init, you can avoid loading after.

Probably the problem is because you are trying to load namespaces before init is finished.

Moreover, it seems you missed the `.json` extension in `addPath` key

Answer (score 0):

It's because your translation files don't load (look at network in console - only status 200 is ok). This methods helped me:

1. Locales must be in public/assets and I had only one file in each folder - translation.json with json object.
2. I use Webpack and if the 1-st method doesn't help, I use the construction:
   `new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: 'assets/locales', to: 'locales' }])` 
   in plugins.

Hope it will help you.